# Quotient of differences

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

In the following, $p$ is a prime and  $i,j,l\in GF(p)$, $i \neq l \neq j$.

$GF(p)=\{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$, isn't it?

I want to show that 
$$\frac{i-j}{i-l}=1+\frac{l-j}{i-l}$$ 
takes all elements of $GF(p)$ besides $0$ and $1$ as $i$ ranges over all elements of $GF(p)$ besides $j$ and $l$.

How can I show this? I would be very helpful for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Originally, I think I misread the question. I think I've answered the correct question now.

Consider the equation
$$\frac{i-j}{i-l}=a,$$
we want to solve this when $a\ne 1$. 
This is the equation $i-j=ai-al$, or $(a-1)i=al-j$,
or $$i=\frac{al-j}{a-1}.$$
Note that this will never be $l$, since then we'd have $j=l$.
Hence the map $f:GF(p)\setminus\{l\}\to GF(p)\setminus\{1\}$ given by
$i\mapsto \frac{i-j}{i-l}$ is surjective, and (since both have $p-1$ elements) therefore bijective.
Then $f(j)=0$, so $f$ induces a bijection from 
$GF(p)\setminus\{j,l\}$ to $GF(p)\setminus\{0,1\}$.

Comment: I want to show, which numbers f(i) or the quotient (which is the same) can take. But you have used, that f maps a finite set to itself. I cannot see this. I thought about $f: \mathbb{Z}_{p} \setminus {\{j,l\}} \to \mathbb{Z}_{p} \setminus{\{0,1\}},\text{ } v \mapsto \frac{i-j}{i-l}$. But the codomain is the thing I want to determine.

Comment: I would be very very helpful for advices!

Comment: Sorry, I think I misread your question originally. Now I've answered it for as $i$ varies.